# Не работают элементы в цикле

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть код:

```
if($("#card_form").length&&(window.initCardComponent=function(e){
    new Vue({el:"#card_form",
    data:{
    valid_to:e.valid_to,
    year:e.year,
    doc_date:e.doc_date,
    cal_config:{format:"DD.MM.YYYY",useCurrent:!1,locale:moment.locale("ru")},
    year_config:{format:"YYYY",useCurrent:!1,locale:moment.locale("ru")},
    class:"input-sm"},
    methods:{watch_valid_to:function(e,t){
    switch(this.veh_type_code){
    case"M3":this.valid_to=moment().add(6,"M").format("DD.MM.YYYY");
    break;
    default:if(this.is_danger){this.valid_to=moment().add(6,"M").format("DD.MM.YYYY");} 
    else 
      if(this.legal_title||this.is_taxi||this.is_education||this.N2||this.N3){
         var n=moment().format("YYYY")-this.year;this.valid_to=n>5?
         moment().add(6,"M").format("DD.MM.YYYY"):moment().add(12,"M").format("DD.MM.YYYY")}    
    else{
      var n=moment().format("YYYY")-this.year;this.valid_to=n<11? 
      moment().add(24,"M").format("DD.MM.YYYY"):moment().add(12,"M").format("DD.MM.YYYY")}}}},
    created:function() 
    {this.watchCollection(["veh_type_code","year","is_taxi","legal_title","is_danger"],
    this.watch_valid_to)}})})
```

В нем не работает строка, а точнее последние три переменные.

```
if(this.legal_title||this.is_taxi||this.is_education||this.N2||this.N3)
```

Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы они начали работать? Может быть я их где-то здесь не указал?

Answer (score 0):

Всё верно, оказывается нужно было добавить v-model с этими элементами в inputs